# Angular - type guard not narrowing types

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

I have interfaces

**Angular Typescript Class**

```
interface A_DTO {
  type: string, 
  commonProperty: string, 
  uniquePropertyA: string, 
  etc..
}

interface B_DTO {
  type: string, 
  commonProperty: string, 
  uniquePropertyB: string,
  etc...
}

type AnyDTO = A_DTO | B_DTO
```

I have an object, fetched from an API. When it is fetched, it immediately gets cast to A_DTO or B_DTO, by reading the 'type' property. But after that, it then it gets saved to a service, for storage, where it gets saved to a single variable, but of typ AnyDTO (I call that service variable with the components I work with - casting back to AnyDTO, doesn't cause any properties to be lost, so I'm happy)

**Angular Template**

But, in a component, I have some template code,

```
@if(object.type == "Type_A") {
 // do something
 // I can do object.commonProperty
 // but I cannot access object.uniquePropertyA
} @ else { object.type == "Type_B") {
 // do something
 // I can do object.commonProperty
 // but I cannot access object.uniquePropertyB
}
```

Note, above, object gets read as type, AnyDTO = A_DTO | B_DTO

**Angular Typescript Class**

I tried creating a type guard on the interface, in the typescript class code, e.g.

```
  protected isTypeA(object: any): object is A_DTO {
    return object?.Type === "Type_A";
  },
```

**Angular Template**

Then

```
@if(isTypeA(object)) {
 // do something
 // I can do object.commonProperty
 // but I still cannot access object.uniquePropertyA...
} @ else { object.type == "Type_B") {
 // do something
 // but I cannot access object.uniquePropertyB
}
```

Even with the typeguard being called in the template, inside the @if, 'object' still gets treated as type: A_DTO | B_DTO. Despite what I read on the internet, type narrowing does not happen. So can only access the common properties from 'object'.

I also tried to explicity type cast in the template, using things like (object as A_DTO).uniquePropertyA, but that doesn't work in the Angular template area

Any ideas on a ***dynamic*** solution, (that ideally does not involve create separate variables for each subtype in the Typescript class)?

Cheers,

ST

Comment: I don't know if you made an error when pasting your code here, but the type predicate is wrong: it does ot make use of  `object` at all. The body should be `return object?.Type === "Type_A";`

Comment: @EricMORAND Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, now corrected the post.

Comment: It sounds like the `AnyDTO` part of the question is a distraction, and that you're trying to ask something like "why does my type guard not guard in my Angular template". That question would make sense even if the type you were narrowing was something as simple as `number | string`. You may get better answers if you simplified the question to focus on the type guard that doesn't narrow the types.

Comment: point taken, I've changed the title of the question to focus more attention on type guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to rewrite you `AnyDTO` to:

```
type AnyDTO = { type: 'Type_A' } & A_DTO | { type: 'Type_B' } & B_DTO;
```

this way TS should treat `AnyDTO` with `Type_A` and `Type_B` differently.

Please note that you use types union `|`, which converts your interfaces to types, so, theoretically you could use `type` and not `interface` for `A_DTO` and `B_DTO`.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gykszv?file=src%2Fcmp%2Fcmp.component.html)

Comment: I redefined AnyDTO as you wrote, but, even then if I do, in Typescript class (let alone the template)... if(isTypeA(object)) {  const val = object // type narrowing still does not happen }, the object still defined as: AnyDTO = { type: 'Type_A' } & A_DTO | { type: 'Type_B' } & B_DTO - so I cannot access val.uniquePropertyA;